# Random Circle Generation in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I am trying to make my personal site a little more interactive by adding parallaxify (https://github.com/hwthorn/parallaxify). I have found the best place to put it (http://puu.sh/5IQZN.png), in a class called `.index-hero`. What I need to do is generate a few (randomly placed) circles, in the shade of: dark blue (#0C76CF) - white (#ffffff). I dont know how to (randomly mix) the two to get a light color. Also (to randomly place circles) I have tried looking at the source code of parallaxify, and saw that they were using math.rand to randomly place the circles in the div, but haven't been able to successfully recreate it. Any help on either part (colors, or placement) would be appreciated and great!

Answer (score 0):

You could create a template div in your html that is hidden, then use javascript to clone it, reveal it and give it randomly placed `top` and `left` values. You can use CSS to set the div's `border-radius` to `50%` for the divs to look like circles. Or instead of a div you could try using the html5 `<canvas>` element to create circles while placing them randomly. [Here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Drawing_shapes) a good place to start.